# Поиск коэффициентов уравнения

Tags: python, математика, scipy, регрессия

В уравнении вида `y = alpha + k*x^n` необходимо найти коэффициенты `alpha`, `k`, `n`. Показатель степени `n` от 0 до 1.

При использовании функции curve_fit из scipy получаются совсем некорректные значения.

Тестовые данные `x = [1021.998 10.21998 5.10999]` `y = [39.8112 15.312 1.5312]`. Должно было получится `alpha = 215.4611` `n = 0.32` `k = 4.3831`. если использовать curve_fit, то на выходе `alpha = -77523.501`; `k=77518, 284`; `n = 0`.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 

def calc_func(x, alpha, k, n): 
    return alpha + k * x ** n

coeff, pcov = curve_fit(calc_func, x[np.isfinite(y)], y[np.isfinite(y)], maxfev=10000)
```

Выяснила, что для такого типа функции такой метод не подходит, нужно решать численными методами минимизации.

Есть ли таких случаев метод решения средствами scipy?
Может есть другой способ решения

Comment: А входные данные какие? Набор точек?

Comment: x, y - одномерные массивы одинаковой длины

Comment: Я бы избавился от степени в уравнении регрессии. Если не ошибаюсь, это получится `log(y-alpha) - log(k) - n*log(x) = 0`

Comment: Можно попробовать. Тогда получается мы линеализируем функцию и возможно метод curve_fit поможет. Спасибо за идею, попробую так.

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста пример данных, на которых получаются некорректные решения. Кроме того, уточните постановку задачи: может ли `x` быть отрицательным, `n` - целое, может ли `n` быть отрицательным, от 0 до 1? Это я к тому, что `x^2` и `x^(-2)` - совсем разные функции, и для них нужно искать приближенное решение по-разному.

Comment: n - рациональное число от 0 до 1, x > 0,  y > 0

Comment: x = [1021.998     10.21998    5.10999]
y = [39.8112 15.312   1.5312]

должно было получится 

alpha = 215.4611

n = 0.32
k = 4.3831

Comment: если использовать curve_fit, то на выходе alpha = -77523.501; k=77518, 284; n = 0

Comment: @todo `curve_fit` хорошо работает только тогда, когда число точек заметно превосходит число параметров. У вас же три параметра и три точки. Ничего удивительного, что поиск сошелся где-то не там. Нужно больше точек.

Comment: Вас кто-то ввёл в заблуждение насчёт ожидаемого решения. При `alpha = 215` вы никак не сможете получить в точке `x=5` значение `y=1.5`. Покажите, как вы искали решение средствами `curve_fit`. Я попробовал - у меня категорически не сходится.

Comment: from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
coeff,  pcov = curve_fit(calc_func, x[np.isfinite(y)], y[np.isfinite(y)], maxfev=10000)

Comment: def calc_func(x, alpha, k, n):
          return alpha + k * x ** n

Answer (score 1):

У вас очень неудачный набор данных. Две точки находятся почти рядом, а третья точка - очень далеко. В результате вычислительная задача получается крайне неустойчивой и `curve_fit` не сходится.

Для решения можно использовать тот факт, что `n` меняется в небольшом диапазоне. Тогда вместо решения задачи с тремя параметрами можно итерировать `n` и вручную выбрать решение.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as spo
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1021.998, 10.21998, 5.10999])
y = np.array([39.8112, 15.312, 1.5312])

def fn(x, a,k,n):
    return a + k*(x**n)

for n in np.linspace(0.01,0.3,20):
    p_1, p_cov_1 = spo.curve_fit(lambda x,a,k: fn(x,a,k, n), x, y )
    err = np.sqrt(np.diag(p_cov_1))
    print("n={0:.3f}, (a,k)={1}±{2}, относительная ошибка {3}".format(n, p_1, err, err/p_1))
```

Получается вот какой результат:

```
n=0.010, (a,k)=[-629.213  624.831]±[162.505 156.627], относительная ошибка [-0.258  0.251]
n=0.025, (a,k)=[-234.577  230.849]±[64.832 58.94 ], относительная ошибка [-0.276  0.255]
n=0.041, (a,k)=[-137.351  134.248]±[40.795 34.886], относительная ошибка [-0.297  0.26 ]
n=0.056, (a,k)=[-93.434  90.929]±[29.96  24.033], относительная ошибка [-0.321  0.264]
n=0.071, (a,k)=[-68.471  66.538]±[23.823 17.874], относительная ошибка [-0.348  0.269]
n=0.086, (a,k)=[-52.407  51.019]±[19.894 13.921], относительная ошибка [-0.38   0.273]
n=0.102, (a,k)=[-41.23   40.362]±[17.178 11.18 ], относительная ошибка [-0.417  0.277]
n=0.117, (a,k)=[-33.025  32.653]±[15.202  9.175], относительная ошибка [-0.46   0.281]
n=0.132, (a,k)=[-26.76   26.862]±[13.708  7.653], относительная ошибка [-0.512  0.285]
n=0.147, (a,k)=[-21.834  22.386]±[12.548  6.463], относительная ошибка [-0.575  0.289]
n=0.163, (a,k)=[-17.868  18.85 ]±[11.628  5.511], относительная ошибка [-0.651  0.292]
n=0.178, (a,k)=[-14.616  16.005]±[10.885  4.737], относительная ошибка [-0.745  0.296]
n=0.193, (a,k)=[-11.906  13.684]±[10.278  4.098], относительная ошибка [-0.863  0.299]
n=0.208, (a,k)=[-9.621 11.768]±[9.775 3.564], относительная ошибка [-1.016  0.303]
n=0.224, (a,k)=[-7.672 10.17 ]±[9.356 3.113], относительная ошибка [-1.219  0.306]
n=0.239, (a,k)=[-5.995  8.826]±[9.004 2.729], относительная ошибка [-1.502  0.309]
n=0.254, (a,k)=[-4.541  7.688]±[8.706 2.401], относительная ошибка [-1.917  0.312]
n=0.269, (a,k)=[-3.27   6.718]±[8.452 2.118], относительная ошибка [-2.585  0.315]
n=0.285, (a,k)=[-2.154  5.887]±[8.236 1.873], относительная ошибка [-3.823  0.318]
n=0.300, (a,k)=[-1.169  5.171]±[8.05  1.659], относительная ошибка [-6.889  0.321]
```

Лично мне нравится `n=0.147`, `alpha = -21.834`, `k = 22.386`. Абсолютная ошибка и относительная приемлемые. Конечно, не идеальные, но терпимые.

[image: approximation]

Видите на графике как сильно изгибается кривая? Это от того, что первые две точки находятся практически на одной вертикали, если сравнивать с правой точкой. Для более качественной аппроксимации желательно, чтобы вторая точка была где-то посередине между первой и третьей.

Так как первые две точки почти на одной вертикали, то `n` должно быть около нуля, чтобы кривая решения быстро росла.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в этом случае очень быстро нарастает абсолютная ошибка для `alpha` и `k`. Как ни крути, очень неудачные данные.

На хороших данных `curve_fit` работает вполне себе успешно.

```
a = -10; k = 3; n = 0.1

u = np.array([1,500,100])
v = fn(u, a,k,n)

p, p_cov = spo.curve_fit(fn, u,v)
```

Результат `p = array([-10. ,   3. ,   0.1])`, ковариационная матрица `p_cov` не определена, так как всего три точки для трёх параметров. Но главное в другом - все три параметра найдены абсолютно точно.

Comment: Спасибо большое за столь подробный ответ. Думаю воспользуюсь Вашим способом, через итерацию по n.

Comment: @todo вам таки нужно больше данных, или же более равномерно распределённых  точек.